# Rails 4 / Turbolinks: Stacking Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

These issues may be unrelated, but I've got a couple of things stacking up as far as javascript goes when I'm using turbolinks:

1) Google analytics. Every time I do a turbolinks navigate to page, another google analytics JS gets stacked into my code at the top of the page:

```
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
...
```

It will keep going on. Also, my pusher connections keep stacking up and go to my limit of 20 for my free account, when there is only 1 user.

Just wondering if anyone has dealt with either of these issues, and if anyone has any idea as what could be causing it, if it could be caused by the same thing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with, at least for the google analytics issue, is to place it in the head tag instead of the body. This fixes the stacking.

Pusher was the same issue.